# How to update QLabel in while loop

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

It feels like I should just be able to set up an event listener that runs an AJAX like call to update a qlabel but this seems to be endlessly complicated with QT.

Basically what I'm attempting to do is update the text in a QLabel. This happens on an infinite loop that breaks when a button is clicked (AKA something like a Slot that contains a flag). The reason for this is I'm essentially reading in a text file on the fly which is updated by the user. When the user saves the text file the content updates on the QLabel. When the user is happy with the text they hit "send". It then kills the listener and E-Mails the text content to a pre-defined E-Mail address. This is work related so the user story has been changed considerably but the overall concept is what I'm going for.

I tried doing something like setting a flag and this listening by doing the following:

```
    while not self.flag_set:
        self.my_text = text_read_module.get_text(self)
        self.label_60.setText(self.my_text)
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()
        sleep(2)
```

I also tried pushing this into it's own process and terminating when the button containing the terminate signal is called

Both of them fail to display any content on the screen but I can tell they're running thanks to some handy dandy print statements

PS This was done in Python but hopefully it is easy to ready for C++ users

Any idea on how to get this working? Thanks!

Comment: There are very few use cases for calling `processEvents` on the main event loop, and calling `sleep` from the main thread is generally a bad idea. Instead of constantly checking for the text you need to be set, use a signal/slot combination.

Comment: I'm not normally a proponent of sleep I was just using it as a stop gap so the it's not running 100+ times a second. I'd definetly prefer to use a signal/slot  combo, how would I do that in this user story?

Comment: Can you not have `text_read_module` emit a signal? Is it part of a non-Qt library?

Comment: If you are in a separate thread it wont work. Changing GUI items like label.setText cause an error in a separate thread. A way around this is to have the thread set a variable with the text then to have a timer periodically update the label text with the variable.

Comment: @HashSplat It is safe to send signals across threads if the connection is queued (and Qt does this automatically when connecting to a slot in another thread). I am not certain how PyQt handles short-circuit signals across threads, but broadly, your statement is false. *Direct* signals and plain function calls to GUI objects across threads are bad, of course.

Comment: @JonHarper Yes, I was referring to direct GUI calls. Signals are safe across threads as long as they are not emitted too quickly.  I have run into several issues with GUI's crashing because a Queued signal was emitted faster than the event loop could handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Qt/PyQt`, the method for triggering callbacks is the Signal/Slot system.  Generally, if you need to continuously do some operation, and occasionally update the GUI based on that operation, you would create a worker thread that sends updates back to the main thread using `Signals`.  For example, you could create a worker thread that continuously checks the file for updates and when it detects a change, it could send data back to the main thread using a signal.  Your main thread GUI would listen for that signal and update the GUI accordingly.

Luckily, in your case, `Qt` already has a class that does this called `QFileSystemWatcher`, so you don't need to manually create a separate thread with signals.

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.watcher = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher(self)
        self.watcher.addPath('/path/to/file')
        self.watcher.fileChanged.connect(self.updateLabel)

    def updateLabel(self, path):
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            self.label.setText(f.read())
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was going for!